# TypeError: get_on_session() missing 1 required positional argument: 'alias' in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

#Creating a dictionary

```
${myPara}     create dictionary   odsResponseType%3DLite     name%3DSeth

create session  mysession   ${base_url}    auth=${auth}     verify=true
${response} =  Get On Session  url=${base_url}  odsResponseType=Lite&name=Seth   params=${myPara}
```

Comment: What library does `get on session` come from? The error seems pretty self-evident. Have you tried adding the `alias` argument?